# as3 timer not stopping nor will reset

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, actionscript, adobe

I'm building a clock in actionscript 3, I want the ability to start, stop and reset the timer. I have working the start. I had the others working but suddenly nothing? I'm not sure if it's because I added more code and put in extra keyframes in the time line, but surely it can't because the start timer works.

Below is my code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var time = new Date();
var seconds = time.seconds;
var minutes = time.minutes;
var hours = time.hours;

var myTimer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
var secondTimer: Timer = new Timer(12000); //12 seconds

myStartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startTimer);
myStopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopTimer);
myResetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetTimer);

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, secondAndMinuteRotate);
secondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, hourRotate);


function startTimer(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    myTimer.start();
    secondTimer.start();
}

function stopTimer(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    myTimer.stop(); //here's my issue
    secondTimer.stop();
}

function resetTimer(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    myTimer.reset(); //and here's my other issue
    secondTimer.reset();
}


function secondAndMinuteRotate(event: TimerEvent): void
{
    mySecondHand.rotation += 6;
    myMinuteHand.rotation += 0.1;
}

function hourRotate(event: TimerEvent): void
{
    myHourHand.rotation += 0.1; 
}

if (hours < 12)
{
    amOrPm.text = "AM";
}
else if (hours > 12)
{
hours = hours - 12;
}


if(hours < 10)
{
    hours = "0" + hours;
}
if(minutes < 10)
{
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

if(seconds < 10)
{
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}

digitalText.text = hours + ':' + minutes + ':'+ seconds;
```

[Link to File on Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41377970/20064376Assignment1.fla)

Comment: Can you provide FLA file? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Is this code from your first frame? If it is and there are more frames, do you come back to the first frame, i.e. are you running in repeat? In that case you probably run into problems because there's many timers getting created instead of just the two. If you use multiple frames, make sure to not go back to the frame that creates the timers. For example you could jump back to the second frame instead (`gotoAndPlay(2)`).

Comment: Yea, that seemed to be the problem. I cut it back to one frame and some of the big issues were fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `stop();` in code of first frame.

Comment: if I add a global stop like that, the digital clock the doesn't start.

Comment: You should place code that is responsible for to digital clock to `secondAndMinuteRotate` function.